# How to center the elements of specific CSS grid's row without horizontal gap and additional wrappers?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Below image has been created by the graphics editor. The target is get the same view by CSS grid.

[image]

Currently, the middle row fills the viewport's width:

[image]

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT"
      "SIDEBAR SPECIFIC_CONTENT"
      "BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT";
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  
  height: 100%;
}
  
  
.TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent {
  
  height: 30px;
  grid-area: UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT;
  background-color: lightpink;
  
  
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar {
  
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SIDEBAR;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 100px;
  
}
    
.TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent {
  
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SPECIFIC_CONTENT;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent {
  
  height: 30px;
  grid-area: BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT;
  background: deepskyblue;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="TwoColumnsLayout">
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent"></div>
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar"></div>
    <main class="TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent"></main>
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent"></div>
  </div>
```

In this case, `justify-content: center;` will change nothing.
If to apply `justify-items: center;` to grid container and also `justify-self: stretch;` to first and last element, we'll get:

[image]

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout {

  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
      "UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT"
      "SIDEBAR SPECIFIC_CONTENT"
      "BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT";
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  justify-items: center;
  
  height: 100%;
}
  
  
.TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent {
  
  height: 30px;
  grid-area: UPPER_FIXED_CONTENT;
  background-color: lightpink;
  justify-self: stretch;
  
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar {
  
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SIDEBAR;
  background-color: gold;
  width: 100px;
  
}
    
.TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent {
  
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-area: SPECIFIC_CONTENT;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent {
  
  height: 30px;
  grid-area: BOTTOM_FIXED_CONTENT;
  background: deepskyblue;
  justify-self: stretch;
  
}
```

```html
  <div class="TwoColumnsLayout">
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent"></div>
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar"></div>
    <main class="TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent"></main>
    <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent"></div>
  </div>
```

I expected it will be simple with CSS grid...
It there the solutions without adding of extra HTML elements?

Comment: You may need one more HTML that wrap sidebar and content together to be a single row. Then controls the center position in that row for sidebar and content.

Comment: @vee, Thank you for the comment. Yes, the additional wrap is the easy solution but I am expecting that vaunted CSS Grid can do without the additional wrapper.

Comment: Yes, of course it can. But your target layout clearly has four grid columns, not two.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pm5x89e2/ This is best I can do but sidebar column will be changed size from `100px` to full 1 grid column.

Comment: @vee, Thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below. The `600px` will simulate the `max-width` which is the area for the sidebar and content

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout {
  --max: 600px; /* your max-width */
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
   calc((100% - var(--max))/2) 100px 1fr calc((100% - var(--max))/2);
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent,
.TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent{
  height: 30px;
  grid-column:1/-1;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar {
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: gold;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent {
  background: deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="TwoColumnsLayout">
  <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-UpperFixedContent"></div>
  <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-Sidebar"></div>
  <main class="TwoColumnsLayout-SpecificContent"></main>
  <div class="TwoColumnsLayout-BottomFixedContent"></div>
</div>
```